# Use firebase preview channel in gitlab merge request

Tags: firebase, gitlab, gitlab-ci, firebase-hosting

I am deploying each merge request to the firebase preview channel and I would like to add generated URL to either comment below the merge request or use the URL for preview like on the print screen [image]

So my questions are

1. how can I parse generated URL from firebase CLI output
2. how can I use the url for "View app" button

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
  script:
    - firebase --project "${FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}" --token "${FIREBASE_TOKEN}" hosting:channel:deploy "${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    - echo "ENVIRONMENT_URL=$(firebase hosting:channel:open live --non-interactive | tail -1 | awk '{ print $3 }')" >> deploy.env
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: $ENVIRONMENT_URL
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: deploy.env
```